# Create list of points from Polygon in geodataframe

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I have a geodataframe that looks like this:

```
ID_0    ISO NAME_0  ID_1    NAME_1  ID_2    NAME_2  TYPE_2  ENGTYPE_2   NL_NAME_2   VARNAME_2   geometry    soyb_a  percent percent_sum
1489    33  BRA Brazil  12  Mato Grosso 1490    Nova Mutum  Município   Municipality    0   0   POLYGON ((-56.61388 -12.87704, -56.57753 -12.8...   1078374.8   2.923144    2.923144
1405    33  BRA Brazil  11  Mato Grosso do Sul  1406    Sapezal Município   Municipality    0   0   POLYGON ((-57.82408 -19.11719, -57.78419 -19.0...   1027233.8   2.784516    5.707660
1529    33  BRA Brazil  12  Mato Grosso 1530    Sapezal Município   Municipality    0   0   POLYGON ((-58.92996 -12.64107, -58.93618 -12.6...   1027233.8   2.784516    8.492176
```

I can see the list of points in the 'geometry' column, but would like to pull those points out and put them in a list. For example, in pandas you can do something like df['column'].to_list(). However, when trying this I get an error:

```
gdf.iloc[0]['geometry'].to_list()

AttributeError: 'Polygon' object has no attribute 'to_list'
```

Any ideas how I can drop the 'Polygon" designation and literally just get the list of points that make up that Polygon? To be clear, I don't want the exterior or boundary of the Polygon, I want all the points inside the boundary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a generic function I use to inspect Polygon content - not sure if it's exactly what you're looking for.   I believe polygons can have arbitrary complexity, so it may be that you can have parts inside of parts:

```
def listPoints(someGeometry):
    '''List the points in a Polygon in a geometry entry - some polygons are more complex than others, so accommodating for that'''    
    pointList = []
    try:
        #Note: might miss parts within parts with this
        for part in someGeometry:
            x, y = part.exterior.coords.xy
            pointList.append(list(zip(x,y)))
    except:
        try:
            x,y = someGeometry.exterior.coords.xy
            pointList.append(list(zip(x,y)))
        except:
            #this will return the geometry as is, enabling you to see if special handling is required - then modify the function as need be
            pointList.append(someGeometry)
    return pointList
```

Then apply as a lambda:

```
gdf.geometry.apply(lambda x: listPoints(x)).values.tolist()
```

[image]

Comment: This isn't quite what I am looking for. I literally want a raw list of floats, which represents the points. Something like [[x,y],[x1,y1],[x2,y2]...]

Comment: Okay - modified my function a bit - I think that's closer to what you need.

Comment: Now that is what I am looking for. Thanks!